# GTM trigger when URL got specific pattern and last integer is larger than constant

Tags: regex, google-tag-manager

I have URL's like this:

```
http://www.example.com/sub1/sub2/sub3/sub4/a/1-2-123456789
```

The format is basically like this:

```
[whatever]/[1 character a-z]/[integer]-[integer]-[integer]
```

I need to create a trigger in GTM that fires when the pagepath follows the mentioned format and the last integer is more than a specific number, for example more than 12345.

Comment: Well, you already defined the pattern. A digit is matched with `[0-9]`, an a-z with `[a-z]`. One or more chars are matched using `+` quantifier. So, have you tried `/[a-z]/[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+`?

Comment: You could dispense with the regex and use a custom javascript variable (i.e. a javascript function) that numerifies (is that a word ?) the number string and compares it to a constant if the rest of the path matches.

Answer (score 0):

GTM doesn't seem to have support for comparing stringified numbers.

The best I could come up with is a combination ORed conditions (combined with pipe '|' operator)

```
(1) Does it match a 6-digited number \d\d\d\d\d\d
(2) Does it match 1234[5-9]
(3) Does it match 1235\d
(4) Does it match 124\d\d
(5) Does it match 13\d\d\d
(6) Does it match 2\d\d\d\d
```